# A Weird Puzzling Machine!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

$${\begin{array}{rcl}\mathsf{\large{PRESENTING}}\end{array}}$$

[image: A Weird Puzzling Machine]

$${\begin{array}{rcl}\mathsf{\large{A}}\ \ \mathsf{\large{WEIRD}}\ \ \mathsf{\large{PUZZLING}}\ \ \mathsf{\large{MACHINE}}\end{array}}$$

**Can you tell me what this machine has to say?**

**Credit - Fleb**

> Now that its solved, puzzle Idea was taken from this awesome [Fleb's Mechanical Puzzle](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8cVJCaye1ns) which is from [The Famine Game](http://www.thefaminegame.com/)

Comment: Looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cVJCaye1ns.

Comment: Yeah. That's right. And rightly added the credit. Thanks

Comment: That wasn't Fleb's puzzle. It's from the [Famine Game](http://www.thefaminegame.com/), a puzzle hunt.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's saying

> UNBLOCKED

Explanation follows...

> The symbols on top (input) and the symbols on bottom (output) when assigned to alphabets in the order

we will get

> A => Z
> B => X
> C => B
> D => U
> E => N
> F => Q
> G => Y
> H => M
> I => A
> J => F
> K => H
> L => P
> M => R
> N => T
> O => S
> P => C
> Q => V
> R => L
> S => D
> T => K
> U => E
> V => W
> W => G
> X => I
> Y => O
> Z => J

and then assigning it, we get

> **DECRYPT US => UNBLOCKED**

Comment: Could you explain the explanation?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan  I hope the explanation is complete now.

Comment: Good explanations! Nice work! :)